# Ambiguity between settings in C#

Tags: c#, settings, ambiguity

I've made an C# app with an GUI and some settings file for user settings. However, when I'm about to read the current values of the settings like `MySettings.Default.SettingsName;` it works perfectly for the first set of settings, say `MyFirstSettings`. For the second however, let's call it `MySecondSettings`, I get an error measure that says `Ambiguity between My first Settings.Default and MySecondSettings.Default`. I haven't been able to find any other way to access the settings but to use the `.Default` though.

Any tips would be really appreciated!

Axel

Comment: Maybe a bit more context would help. What kind of "settings" are you using? Built in to Visual Studio?

Comment: Would this SO article and answer help? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14371817/ambiguity-between-variables-in-c-sharp

Comment: @kmort: Yes it's the settings built in to Visual Studio I used, those you add by creating a new item and choose settings. After creating that the only thing I changed was the variables, not the name nor the location of the file.

Comment: @Philip: Well, maybe it would if I was a bit more of a programmer but I don't get how I should apply that to my problem, sorry!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you to have two settings files, it would generally work without any problems:

The following works (and compiles) for me perfectly:

```
Settings1.Default.Value1 = "11";
Settings1.Default.Save();

Settings2.Default.Value1 = "22";
Settings2.Default.Save();
```

So, the problem might occur if you created/copied the Settings2 file in some own and not really "fair" way outside of VisualStudio (for instance). (In that case both settings file might be refering still to the same "Settings1" class).

---

*The way I created Settings2 file is to drag-n-drop in solution explored (with Ctrl key pressed (copying)) and renamed it from "Copy of Settings1" to just "Settings2".*

*Selecting "Add/New Items..." and selecting a new settings file works also greatly.*

**EDIT:**

As the author of the question commented below:

> In the DAQSettings "folder" I found two instances of the Designer, one
>   named Day Settings1.Designer and one just named Settings.Designer.

... explains what was wrong in there, as there was a duplication (duplicate naming) for certain classes/elements, so the way to clear the problem is a "manual involving".

Comment: Thanks a lot for the answer! At this point all I've trying to do is to read the values into a text box, that is the opposite of your example. But I guess the procedure is the same. Anyway, I created both settings file using the standard visual studio way and haven't changed anything but the values in them since then. I've not moved them either, should them be in properties? They contain different variables by the way, since they are settings for different types of sensors connected to the computer. I assume one can then create new instances setting the parameters like in a regular object?

Comment: You should provide more details on your code then (or some other "tricky" moments from there).

Comment: Sure!

AccelerometerName.Text = AccelerometerSettings.Default.accelerometerName; and

AccelerometerResolution.Text = Convert.ToString(AccelerometerSettings.Default.accelerometerResolution);

Works like a charm!

DAQName.Text = DAQSettings.Default.daqName;

Gives this strange errors...

(I admit the names are a mess, but if it's not ovbvious capital first letter is the name of the setting and versal first is the name of the textbox I want to give the value of the setting).

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Open your `AccelerometerSettings.Designer.cs` and `DAQSettings.Designer.cs` files and check on which exactly class names are defined there.

Comment: I think you're on to something here! In the DAQSettings "folder" I found two instances of the Designer, one named Day Settings1.Designer and one just named Settings.Designer. Removing them both and creating DAQSettings again did the trick, many thanks for the help!

Comment: Aha. Will update the answer now to have more details about the problem specific. But still, that's strange how could that happen...

Answer (score 1):

In my case, I actually had a setting in the default settings file name `Default`. This caused an error that said

```
 Ambiguity between Settings.Default and Settings.Default
```

Changing this resolved the error.

***Note**:Yes, naming that setting 'Default' was a bad idea, however this is an extremely small program that does one thing, so if someone were to come behind me and look at this, they would probably know what it was for.*

Answer (score 0):

I had the error "Ambiguity between Settings.Default and Settings.Default"
I went in the Settings.Designer.cs then removed an internal class that was made at the bottom named "Default".